# Adding text to menu in nav bar pushes button off.

Tags: html, css, menu, positioning, navbar

It's my first time posting a question so here's to hoping I haven't violated any commandants - here's my issue:

I made a nav bar for my site as shown below. However, whenever I add the text (see: Home) it pushes the menu button off the nav bar. I've tried tinkering with the margins and padding, but to no avail. I'll include the full HTML off the site below in case it's needed.

Thanks folks!

Edit: I've made a jsfiddle to illustrate my point better.

http://jsfiddle.net/6JK3E/

```
<div id="nav">

            <div class="menubutton">

                    <div class="menustyle">

                        <a href="#">

                            Home

                        </a>

                    </div>

                </a>

            </div>

            <div class="menubutton">

            </div>

            <div class="menubutton">

            </div>

            <div class="menubutton">

            </div>

            <div class="menubutton">

            </div>

            <div class="lastmenubutton">

            </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
    #wrapper
{
width:950;
height:100%;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 16px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 16px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
min-height: 1045px;
background-color: white;
}

#header
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 200px;
}

#logo
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 140px;
background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#bluebar1
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(86, 177, 255, 1);
background-color: rgba(103, 185, 255, 0.43);
}

#bluebar2
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 10px;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(86, 177, 255, 1);
background-color: rgba(103, 185, 255, 0.43);
margin-top: -1px;
}

#bluebar3
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 10px;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(86, 177, 255, 1);
background-color: rgba(103, 185, 255, 0.43);
margin-top: 1px;
}

#nav
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 50px;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.47);
}

.menubutton
{
width: 144px;
height: 48px;
background-color: white;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
border-right: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.47);
}

.lastmenubutton
{
width: 144px;
height: 48px;
background-color: white;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}

/*** Menu Buttons ***/

.menustyle
{   
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
font-size: 18px;
color: rgb(0, 54, 80);
}

/***                       ***/
```

Full Site HTML and CSS:

```
    <html>

    <title>BlueCloudGaming</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet/style.css"/>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="description" content="">

    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700|Lora|Open+Sans|Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">

        <div id="bluebar1">

        </div>

        <div id ="logo">

        </div>

        <div id="nav">

            <div class="menubutton">

                    <div class="menustyle">

                        <a href="#">

                            Home

                        </a>

                    </div>

                </a>

            </div>

            <div class="menubutton">

                <a href="#">

                    Home

                </a>

            </div>

            <div class="menubutton">

            </div>

            <div class="menubutton">

            </div>

            <div class="menubutton">

            </div>

            <div class="lastmenubutton">

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="bluebar2">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="servertitlewrap">

            <div class="servertitle">

                <a href="#"><div class="servertitlefont">

                    Trouble in Terrorist Town

                </div>

                <div class="serverp">

                    Click to connect!

                </div></a>

            </div>

                <div class="servertitlediv">

                </div>

            <div class="servertitle">

                <a href="#"><div class="servertitlefont">

                    DarkRP v.3.1.6b

                </div>

                <div class="serverp">

                    Click to connect!

                </div></a>

            </div>

                <div class="servertitlediv">

                </div>

            <div class="servertitle">

                <a href="#"><div class="servertitlefont">

                    Starbound

                </div>

                <div class="serverp">

                    Click to connect!

                </div></a>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="textwrapper">

            <div class="textblock">

                <div class="servertextstyle">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas a massa turpis. Vestibulum quis odio a sapien suscipit congue eget ut justo. Phasellus lectus ligula, egestas ac leo sed, lacinia convallis mi. Nam dapibus, purus a iaculis vulputate. Nam dapibus, purus.
                </div>

            </div>

                <div class="blockdivider">

                </div>

            <div class="textblock">

                <div class="servertextstyle">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas a massa turpis. Vestibulum quis odio a sapien suscipit congue eget ut justo. Phasellus lectus ligula, egestas ac leo sed, lacinia convallis mi. Nam dapibus, purus a iaculis vulputate. Nam dapibus, purus.
                </div>

            </div>

                <div class="blockdivider">

                </div>

            <div class="textblock">

                <div class="servertextstyle">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas a massa turpis. Vestibulum quis odio a sapien suscipit congue eget ut justo. Phasellus lectus ligula, egestas ac leo sed, lacinia convallis mi. Nam dapibus, purus a iaculis vulputate. Nam dapibus, purus.
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="serverwrapper">

            <div class="serverblock">

                <div class="borderadius"><img src="img/server1.png">

                </img></div>

            </div>

                <div class="blockdivider">

                </div>

            <div class="serverblock">

                <div class="borderadius"><img src="img/server2.png">

                </img></div>

            </div>

                <div class="blockdivider">

                </div>

            <div class="serverblock">

                <div class="borderadius"><img src="img/server3.png">

                </img></div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="bannerpic">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">

        <div id="servers">

        </div>

            <div id="footdivider">

            </div>

        <div id="footlogo">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="bluebar3">

        </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Full CSS for the site:

```
    html
{
height: 100%;
}

body
{
height: 100%;
background-color: white;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background-image: url("../img/sky2.jpg");
}

a
{
text-decoration:none;
}

#wrapper
{
width:950;
height:100%;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 16px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 16px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
min-height: 1045px;
background-color: white;
}

#header
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 200px;
}

#logo
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 140px;
background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#bluebar1
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(86, 177, 255, 1);
background-color: rgba(103, 185, 255, 0.43);
}

#bluebar2
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 10px;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(86, 177, 255, 1);
background-color: rgba(103, 185, 255, 0.43);
margin-top: -1px;
}

#bluebar3
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 10px;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(86, 177, 255, 1);
background-color: rgba(103, 185, 255, 0.43);
margin-top: 1px;
}

#nav
{
width: 950px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
height: 50px;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.47);
}

.menubutton
{
width: 144px;
height: 48px;
background-color: white;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
border-right: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.47);
}

.lastmenubutton
{
width: 144px;
height: 48px;
background-color: white;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}

/*** Menu Buttons ***/

.menustyle
{   
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
font-size: 18px;
color: rgb(0, 54, 80);
}

/***                       ***/

#content
{
width:950px;
height:600px;
margin-top:10px;
}

#textwrapper
{
width: 950px;
height: 250px;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
}

#serverwrapper
{
width: 950px;
height: 220px;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
}

.textblock
{
display: inline-block;
height: 200px;
width: 250px;
background-color: azure;
margin-top: 25px;
border:1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.47);
overflow:hidden;
border-radius:5px;
}

.blockdivider
{
width:40px;
display:inline-block;
}

/* ----------------- */

#servertitlewrap
{
width: 950px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.77);
}

.servertitle
{
display: inline-block;
height: 50px;
width: 250px;
background-color: rgba(166, 214, 255, 1);
margin-top: 25px;
border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.servertitlediv
{
width:40px;
display:inline-block;
}

.servertitlefont
{
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
font-size:18px;
margin-top:4px;
color: rgb(0, 54, 80);
}

.serverp
{
font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color: dimgray;
}

/* ----------------- */

.serverblock
{
display: inline-block;
height: 160px;
width: 250px;
background-color: azure;
margin-top: 25px;
border: 1px solid rgba(107, 107, 107, 1);
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

#bannerpic
{
width:950px;
height:100px;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.47);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.47);
}

#footer
{
height: 152px;
width: 950px;
margin-top:70px;
}

#servers
{
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
background-color: rgba(166, 214, 255, 1);
border-right: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.47);
margin-top: 3px;
display: inline-block;
}

#footlogo
{
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
background-color: rgba(166, 214, 255, 1);
border-left: 1px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.47);
margin-top: 3px;
display: inline-block;
}

#footdivider
{
width: 340px;
height: 150px;
display: inline-block;
}

.servertextstyle
{
padding: 15px;
text-align: justify;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}

.borderadius
{
border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: looks huge code. better to remove empty lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dxW8Y/) what you are trying to do? I change and add some **CSS**.
I put display:inline-block on nav

```
#nav{
display:inline-block;
}
```

and add

```
.menubutton{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank-you very much! I'll just implement this fix, and if it works I'll close the question. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing `</a>` tag. Delete this.

You should also have a DOCTYPE declaration, and details such as title should be in the head-tag.

.. and img's don't have a closing tag.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I must have accidently removed it at some point. I've taken away the </a> and added <!DOCTYPE HTML> - also, the width of the wrapper wasn't defined properly (950 / 950px) so I've changed that too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

add `vertical-align: top` to .menubutton or remove the height then just add `line-height` to center the text vertically, (NOTE: line-height applys to one line text only or else it'll be a mess)